# silverlight animation question

Tags: silverlight, animation

Doe's anybody knows what wrong with markup below

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="DoubleAnim.MainPage"
    Width="640" Height="480">
    <UserControl.Resources> 
        <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" Storyboard.TargetName="objectToAnimate">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="400"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>                
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Rectangle x:Name="objectToAnimate" Fill="#FF0000F9" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Canvas.Top="164"  Height="100" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="192" RadiusY="8" RadiusX="8" >
        </Rectangle>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="132,180,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Everything looks good but it not works:((
Doe's silverlight know how to animate canvas.top and canvas.left?
Or maybe that I have missed something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a canvas object. Replace Grid with Canvas.

Answer (score 2):

The [Canvas.Top](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.top%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and [Canvas.Left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.left%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) attached properties are only used if the Rectangle (or UIElement) is hosted in a [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms609101%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) panel. The [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) uses different logic and attached properties to layout it's children.

Comment: THANX GUYS!I DIDN'T MENTIONED THIS!